# Orbeon Forms: How to use xPath within an Action

Tags: orbeon

Another silly question from a beginner:

How do you use xPath within an Action?

```
   <xf:action observer="GetURL-control" event="DOMActivate" type="xpath">
        var mySysResult = 'true' 
       xf:if ((mySysResult = 'true') then (/SystemResult = mySysResult) else 
              (/SystemResult =mySysResult = 'false'))
    </xf:action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm usually writing simple logic into `value` attribute in `xf:setvalue`, like this:

```
<xf:action observer="GetURL-control" event="DOMActivate">
    <xf:setvalue ref="//SystemResult" value="if (xxf:non-blank(//control-1)) then 'true' else 'false'"/>
</xf:action>
```

You can use `if` statement even as attribute of `xf:action`. This can be helpful if you have more elements under `xf:action`.

```
<xf:action observer="GetURL-control" event="DOMActivate" if="//SystemResult = 'OK'">
   <xf:setvalue ref="//SystemResult" value="'OK'"/>
   <xf:setvalue ref="//SystemResult2" value="'OK'"/>
</xf:action>
```