# Orbeon Forms: IF/THEN/ELSE Statement using Actions with xPath

Tags: orbeon

I tried both of these IF statements in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74665505/orbeon-forms-how-to-use-xpath-within-an-action?rq=1), but neither work.

However, they do work OK if you remove the `type="xpath"` statement ( see [this](https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/d2cc705db5472a1b7579fe06ed439f98bf368df2) form).

So how can you use an action with the `type="xpath"` statement with:

- If/then/else in the action header
- If/then/else in action body

A simple example would be great.

Many thanks in advance

PeteA

Answer (score 2):

Those examples shouldn't have had that `type="xpath"` attribute. I just removed those attributes from that answer to avoid possible confusion.

The `type="xpath"` attribute on an `xf:action` is used to specify that the action should run a server-side XPath script. This is particularly useful when using extension functions that have side effects. You can find more about this in the section [Calling server-side XPath](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/actions/scripting#calling-server-side-xpath).

Comment: Thanks Alex,
Could you give some xPath examples for the action header and action body please.
PeteA

Comment: @PeteAtkin I am not really sure I understand what you are asking about. If you want to set `foo` to 42, you do `<xf:setvalue ref="//foo" value="42"/>`. But if you only want to do this when `bar` is 43, then you do `<xf:setvalue if="//bar = 43" ref="//foo" value="42"/>`. Does that make sense?

Comment: What I dont yet understand is how this kind of format can be used: 
<xf:action observer="XXXX-control" event="DOMActivate" type="xpath">
where the type="xpath" is in the action header??

Nor do I understand the repeated use of "foo" in much of Orbeon's documentation!!

And the format of these comments is awful...

PeteA

Comment: @PeteAtkin Let's try to make sense of this. First, when you use the term "header", I think you mean "attribute". In XML, if you have `<a b="c">`, `a` is an element, `b` is an attribute, and `c` is the value of the `b` attribute.

Comment: @PeteAtkin Second, the `type="xpath"` attribute is used on an `<xf:action>` if what you put inside that element is XPath you want to run on the server. But so far I haven't seen any case you mentioned that would need this, so you can maybe just ignore this for now.

Comment: @PeteAtkin Third, `foo`, `bar` are often used as placeholder names (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar).

Comment: @PeteAtkin Fourth, and finally, yes, comments here on Stack Overflow are quite limited. And I think this is intentional, as they can easily get overused, in place of asking other questions, or using some other system to have an out-of-band discussion. Note that you can use the backticks in comments around code, to make it easier to read. Does this add a little bit of clarity to the above answer?

Comment: @PeteAtkin Just checking: did you manage to write the XForms you needed for this?

Comment: We can write the xPath code fine in an action.

My confusion is over the use of the xPath, i.e. when would I specifiy xPath in the action header, and when to use it in the action body.
We already using the body option, so its the header option which I cant seem to get working.
PeteA

Comment: @PeteAtkin You use an `<xf:action if="…">…</xf:action>` to have what is inside the `<xf:action>` only run when the `if` condition is true. In that case, what is inside the `<xf:action>` is other XForms actions (other `<xf:action>`, `<xf:setvalue>`, etc). But if you want to say that what is inside the `<xf:action>` is an XPath expression that you just want to be evaluated, then you add that `type="xpath"` attribute. In that case, the result from the XPath is "discarded", so that will typically be used to run some code that has a side effect.